# Does magnetism of metals increase when they are irradiated?

Tags: radiation, magnetic-moment, metals

Metals have magnetic properties because they are crystal structures with unpaired electrons moving around through them, these unpaired electrons have a net spin. Does irradiating a metal increase the number of unpaired electrons, and, the magnetism of the metal?

Comment: What makes you think that it does?

Comment: Irradiate with what? But, generally, adding disorder to the material is not going to help most mechanisms for magnetism.

Comment: @Gert what makes you think it does not?

Comment: @JonCuster electromagnetic radiation

Comment: "It suffices a tiny amount of energy, to levitate an electron into an unoccupied state, to make it traveling through the entire crystal" https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_iron_a_magnetic_metal_but_aluminum_is_not

Comment: Electronic states in the band structure already extend through the entire crystal. And, in a metal, there are lots of unoccupied states at and around the Fermi surface - there are no significant barriers to electrons moving around in a metal, magnetic or otherwise.